# TextField delegate method not being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on iOS 5 targeted project. I am facing a very strange issue. I am setting the

delegate for my textfield as

```
self.myTextField.delegate=self;(in viewDidLoad)
```

and even tried setting the delegate in nib as well . But neither of them triggers the

following textField delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

I even tried giving the action for textField ,this didn't work as well. I wonder is this a

issue in iOS5. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `UITextFieldDelegate` in your .h file

Comment: Are you definitely using a text field and not a text view?

Comment: Yea I am using textField itself

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint on protocols and check is it going on these protocol or not?

Comment: Yes I have put the break point.Its not going inside

Comment: it's not possible to help you unless you post some code

Comment: Ok I got my mistake . My textField s user interaction is disabled in nib. The data I am entering to the textField is through my customized keypad.When I manually click this textField the delegate method is called properly

Answer (score 1):

check these points,

first check the protocol, `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in interface

check the property of `IBOutlet` is attached with view or not;

remember connection with outlet is very improtant

then in `viewDidLoad` check `[self.txtField setDelegate:self];`

then delegate Methods

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 0):

did you provide the same assigned iboutlet object in view did load. If your have created from pragramatically used load View and assigned a view it. or else check whether using any animation part, please comment it & verify it.

Comment: Ok I got my mistake . My textField s user interaction is disabled in nib. The data I am entering to the textField is through my customized keypad.When I manually click this textField the delegate method is called properly.

Comment: Plz verify your code first and analyze it again and again. It will boost your analytical ability. Mr Raj